# Pass data between controller without any kind of storyboard reference

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to pass data between a tableview and a viewcontroller.
For reason that i don't repeat here, I created the view controller programmatically, just via code and without any kind of reference and presence in the storyboard (I have not the ViewController in the Storyboard). Everything work fine, also the graphical transition, but the data transition.
I performed the data transition in "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" before the graphical transition.

In ViewController

```
var purchase:Purchase?
```

In TableViewController

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var arrayToUse:NSArray?
    var tableInUse:UITableView?
    let dc = DetailsViewController() 

   // Retrive the correct data here 

    let indexPath = tableInUse?.indexPathForSelectedRow
    dc.purchase = arrayToUse?.objectAtIndex((indexPath?.row)!) as! Purchase
    let temp = arrayToUse?.objectAtIndex((indexPath?.row)!) as! Purchase
    print(temp.title)

    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(DetailsViewController(), animated: true)
}
```

I looked at different solution found here and in other site, but I always found solution contemplating "segue" or "nib".
What I'm doing wrong?

I hope that I made clear
Every kind of help or tips are really welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you are creating an instance of `DetailsViewController` and setting the data to it, but pushing another `DetailsViewController` object. You should use previously created `dc` object instead of creating a new instance.

Instead of:

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(DetailsViewController(), animated: true)
```

You should use:

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(dc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thank you. It was so simple. Sometimes Ti trip myself up. Thank  you again